# Quickly changing values of environment variables in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell

For historical reasons, deploying one of our tools relies on two different versions of Java at various stages in the process. The way this is handled is by repeatedly editing the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `.bash_profile.`

For example, the deployment instructions has a step in the middle like this:

1. Edit `.bash_profile` to uncomment the following line:

`JAVA_HOME=/path//to/java/jdk1.6.0_07/`

2. source `.bash_profile`
3. ~~First deployment steps~~
4. Edit `.bash_profile` to comment out the previous line and uncomment the following line:
   `JAVA_HOME=/path//to/java/jdk1.7.0_47/`
5. source `.bash_profile`
6. ~~More deployment steps~~

This is quite obviously a braindead way of doing this.

What's the quickest/shortest/most correct way of changing an environment variable on the fly?

Comment: Isn't this the purpose of the export command in bash?  EXPORT FOO=bar

Comment: since the steps seem to be repeatedly sourcing .bash_profile, it sounds like it's all one shell environment that's running these deployment steps, in which case you can just keep resetting JAVA_HOME to whatever value you want: `export JAVA_HOME; cd /; JAVA_HOME=/here/there; cd /; deploy 1; JAVA_HOME=/other/place; deploy 2`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Relying on an obscure shell function such as `export` is the wrong way to solve this problem. The preferred way of doing this is simply to automate the process: condense the manual steps into a script (or preferably its own Java program), then monitor the progress of the deployment through a separate program (ideally running on a different server for Separation of Concerns) and change `.bash_profile` at the appropriate point in the process - determined by querying the filesystem periodically. The actual installer should wait for `.bash_profile` to be adjusted before continuing.

Comment: @JeffSchaller (cont.) The main installer should instruct the helper program to begin the renaming process, communicating over e.g. CORBA.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the purpose of export (built-in function) in bash?  `export FOO=bar`  See [man pages for bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).